# Add class to a parent that contains an ul child

Tags: jquery, html

So i have a "ul" within and "li" for a drop down menu. Like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Link 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">SubLink 1</a>
<li><a href="">SubLink 2</a>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to add a class to each anchor contained in the "li" that has the "ul". In this case i want to add it to the "Link 1".

I tried to add it to the "li" that contains the "ul" child but it doesn't seem to work. I dunno why. I tried serverl methods but no results. I'm not that skilled with jquery :)

I tried this:

```
$('ul li:has(ul)').addClass('someclass');
```

which i placed in my "$(document).ready"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
$('ul li ul').siblings('a').addClass('someclass');
```

Result will be:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="" class="someClass">Link 1</a>
      <ul>
          <li>
              <a href="">SubLink 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="">SubLink 2</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) function of jquery like this :

```
$( "li" ).has( "ul" ).addClass('someclass');
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hcsZs/)

Answer (score 0):

You said you need to add it to the *anchor*, but your code was adding it to the `li`.

If you want to add it to the anchor:

```
$('ul li:has(ul)').children('a').addClass('someclass');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IPiRoRO/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IPiRoRO/1/edit)

Or all in the selector:

```
$('ul li:has(ul) > a').addClass('someclass');
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/IPiRoRO/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/IPiRoRO/2/edit)

Comment: @user2606526: With the structure as quoted, and the code above, it works; see the live links.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not very efficient, but you could

```
$('ul li ul').parent().parent().addClass('someclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you add an `id` attribute to the parent `ul` element so that there aren't any problems with other elements on the page. I added an `id` attribute of `dropdown` to the parent element.

Anytime there is a `ul` element within `div#dropdown` it will add a class to the links within the nested `ul` element.

```
$(function(){
    $('#dropdown ul a').addClass('someclass'); 
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HMzLh/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the ul exists to add a simple class, you can just target the child ul in the jQuery selector. Here is an example:

```
// Add Class to LI with Child UL (Level 1)
$('.menuContainer li ul').parent().addClass('hasChild');
```

After you added the class to all list items, you can simply target your anchor using the > selector, like this in jQuery `$('li.hasChild > a')` or the same in CSS.

---

You can check the link below to see live examples (also with level 2 lists) and more details about the code:

http://html-tuts.com/add-class-to-parent-li-if-has-child-ul/